# How to store centrality values in a file sequentially?

Tags: csv, networking, netlogo

I'm using network extension "nw"I calculated centrality metric like  betweenness   and  I'm trying to print the values of nodes sequentially to
csv files 
I wish the result consist two column the first is turtle-id and second the betweenness of turtle

---

--
and so on

```
to save
```

file-open "turtles.csv"

Let Dk1 [ nw:betweenness-centrality] of turtle-set sort turtles

if is-number? Dk1 [ set Dk1 precision Dk1 2 ]

```
 file-print(word  "betweenness-centrality: " Dk1)


file-close ;
```

end

The result of this code changes every time it is executed and  They are different from what they appear in world

Answer (score 2):

Remember that [agentsets](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#agentsets) in NetLogo are unordered while lists are ordered. The [`sort`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sort) primitive returns a list. In this case, `sort turtles` returns a list of turtles sorted by `who` number. However, if you then turn that list back into a `turtle-set` you'll lose the ordered properties of the list.

Instead of using the `of` primitive to get a list of `betweenness-centrality` values in an agentset, just iterate over the list that is returned by `sort`. For example:

```
foreach sort turtles [ a-turtle -> show [who] of a-turtle ]
```

Comment: Excuse me,could you explain more

Comment: what part or parts of this would you like explained?